# Failed to start Angular project

Tags: npm, angular-cli

After install using `npm i` run my project `npm run build` and i got this error

[image]

I also remove node_modules and `npm i` both on Windows and Ubuntu (Wsl2)

Comment: I'm not familiar with `ngx-portal` but I'd start with removing that package from the package.json and do another install. There's a package in the [material cdk to handle portals](https://material.angular.io/cdk/portal/overview) if you just need that piece of functionality.

Comment: You try delete package-lock.json and build again